# Need to change logic on filtering of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am filtering my JSON content with checkboxes. The code below works, except I need to change the logic. Currently, if you select a single checkbox and hit submit it will show all items that have that value of "Y". Now the problem is that if you select multiple checkboxes and hit submit, rather than it showing everything that is for example "organic" and "bpa-free", its only showing items that have "Y" for both values. So when both are checked, an item must have "Y" for both organic and bpa-free. If one has "Y" but not the other, it doesnt show the other item. How can i make it so its filtering by all products rather than just showing items that match the criteria exactly? Does this make sense? Basically i just want to show everything that has a "Y" that matches what is selected in the checkboxes to show. I have included a sample below thanks!

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mutx4tbo/)

```
 var sampleItems = [{
  name : "All",
  gmoFree : 'Y',
  bpaFree : 'Y',
  glutenFree : 'Y',
  lowSodium : 'Y',
  kosherSym : 'Y',
  organic : 'Y'
}, {
  name : "None",
  gmoFree : 'N',
  bpaFree : 'N',
  glutenFree : 'N',
  lowSodium : 'N',
  kosherSym : 'N',
  organic : 'N'
}, {
  name : "GMO and Gluten Free",
  gmoFree : 'Y',
  bpaFree : 'N',
  glutenFree : 'Y',
  lowSodium : 'N',
  kosherSym : 'N',
  organic : 'N'
}];

$('#submitFilter').click(function() {
var availableFilters = [];
  var activeFilters = [];
  var $filters = $('.filters').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    availableFilters.push(value);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      activeFilters.push(value);
    }
  });
  var filteredItems = sampleItems.filter(function(item) {
    return availableFilters.every(function(filter) {
      if (activeFilters.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        return item[filter] === 'Y';
      }
      return true;
    });
  });
  var $list = $('#list').empty();
  $.each(filteredItems, function(index, item) {
    $list.append($('<LI>').text(JSON.stringify(item)));
  });
});

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-gulten" value="glutenFree">Gluten Free</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-non-gmo" value="gmoFree">Non-GMO</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-organic" value="organic">Organic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-low-sodium" value="lowSodium">Low Sodium</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-bpa-free" value="bpaFree">BPA Free</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="filters"
                  name="filter-kosher"  value="kosherSym">Kosher</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="submitFilter" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="clearFilter" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
</form>
<h2>Results</h2>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: those are two different searches. you need to add a button that switches between (a) search results for any match and (b) search results for all matches. `search any match` filters items based on `> 0` property matches, whereas `search all matches` must return a reduction in your filter callback

Comment: i suggest to change the data structure to use simple boolean values instead of strings with `'Y'` or `'N'`. then you could just check the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed a small amount of the javascript code from your Fiddle:

```
$('#submitFilter').click(function() {
  var availableFilters = [];
  var activeFilters = [];
  var $filters = $('.filters').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    availableFilters.push(value);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      activeFilters.push(value);
    }
  });
  var filteredItems = sampleItems.filter(function(item) {
    // Changed here *************
    if (!activeFilters.length) return true;
    for (var i = 0; i < activeFilters.length; i++) {
      if(item[activeFilters[i]] === 'Y') return true;
    }
    return false;
    // to here *************
  });
  var $list = $('#list').empty();
  $.each(filteredItems, function(index, item) {
    $list.append($('<LI>').text(JSON.stringify(item)));
  });
});
```

Summary of steps:

- If there are no filters, return true
- Check each filter and return true if matched
- If no filters matched, return false

Comment: thank you so much! This solved my problem!! Works perfectly!